# Set elements' id in a for loop

Tags: javascript, html, dom, for-loop

I am trying to create a function, which counts the `li` elements, and then give them `id="listItem1"`, `id="listItem2"` and so on. The problems is that `j` is always equal to 0, and I can't understand why. Here is the code. I am adding `li` elements to a list dynamically, but no matter how many they are, they always get `id="listItem0"` :

```
function countLi() {

    var liCount = document.getElementsByTagName("li").length;

    for (j = 0; j < liCount; j++) {

        document.getElementsByTagName("li")[j].id = "listItem" + j;
        document.getElementsByTagName("input")[j + 1].id = "checkbox" + j;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try declaring `j` like `var j = 0`. How are you running `countLi`?

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED: http://jsbin.com/ERAqIVaj/1/edit?html,js,output

Don't use document.getElementsByTagName in your loop because of performance.

```
function countLi() {
    var li = document.getElementsByTagName("li"),
        input = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

    for (j = 0; j < li.length; j++) {
        li[j].id = "listItem" + j;
        input[j].id = "checkbox" + (j + 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try-

```
 function countLi() {

        var liCount = document.getElementsByTagName("li").length;

        for (var j = 0; j < liCount; j++) {

            document.getElementsByTagName("li")[j].id = "listItem" + j;
            document.getElementsByTagName("input")[j + 1].id = "checkbox" + j;
        }
    }
```

Or

```
function countLi() {

    var liCount = document.getElementsByTagName("li").length;
    var j;
    for (j=0; j < liCount; j++) {

        document.getElementsByTagName("li")[j].id = "listItem" + j;
        document.getElementsByTagName("input")[j + 1].id = "checkbox" + j;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you declare `var j=0` then just `for (;j < liCount; j++)`

Comment: I've tried this already, giving v j = 0 somewhere above, but it doesn't work. I also tried var idCount = 0 and than wirting idCount++ in at the begining of the statement for the for cicle. For some reason it stays 0 :/

Comment: If you have forgotten to declare loop variables (or other variables) throughout your code that may cause unexpected issues as they create implicit globals. Try to put your code on [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/) and fix all the issues if any.